# changing the graph color in vtiger

Tags: vtiger

I am using Vtiger CRM. I want to change the horizontal and vertical graph colors in dashboard. I tried doing in `modules/dashboard/horizontal_bargraph.php` and `modules/dashboard/vertical_bargraph.php` but its changing.

I have been trying to solve this problwm from 1 week. Please help me in this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the lines that you require to change are in '/modules/Dashboard/vertical_bargraph.php'

```
if($theme == 'bluelagoon')
    $fill =& Image_Graph::factory('gradient', array(IMAGE_GRAPH_GRAD_HORIZONTAL_MIRRORED, 'blue', 'white'));

elseif($theme == 'softed')
    $fill =& Image_Graph::factory('gradient', array(IMAGE_GRAPH_GRAD_HORIZONTAL_MIRRORED, 'blue', 'white'));

else
    $fill =& Image_Graph::factory('gradient', array(IMAGE_GRAPH_GRAD_HORIZONTAL_MIRRORED, 'black', 'white'));
```

I had a go at changing the values and it worked. Just read the if statement and work out what theme your vTiger is set to